# Why Vanilophp don't use webpack by default?

Tags: laravel, webpack, vite, vanilo

I just installed VaniloPHP by following the instruction on the documentation with Laravel 9 but Laravel Mix don't install, instead LaravelVite is installed, it's normal ?

Because of that I can’t manage to build app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel 9 migrated completely from Mix to Vite.

If you want to use Mix you can follow the official Guide to migrate manually back to Laravel Mix:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#migrating-back-to-mix